# Вийти чи зійти на наступній зупинці

Tags: вживання-слів

Діалог з сьогоднішньої поїздки в метрополітені.  На наступній зупинці мені потрібно вийти, переді мною стоїть дідусь, запитую:

- На наступній будете виходити?
- Вийти можна заміж.
- На наступній будете сходити?
- Зійти можна з глузду.

Моя зупинка, дідусь не зрушив з місця. Довелося проштовхуватися.
Я так і не зрозуміла та й не знаю, ***як правильно потрібно було запитати.***

З СУМ-11

> [ВИХОДИТИ, джу, диш, недок., ВИЙТИ, йду, йдеш; мин. ч. вийшов, йшла,
> ло; док.](http://sum.in.ua/s/vykhodyty)
>
> **1.** Іти звідки-небудь назовні, за межі чогось. **2.** перен. Вибувати звідки-небудь, з чогось, залишати якийсь заклад, установу, організацію і т. ін..... **15.** за кого
> (також із сл. заміж). Одружуватися, ставати чиєю-небудь дружиною,
> жінкою.
>
> [ЗІЙТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/zijty) див. сходити
>
> [СХО́ДИТИ і рідше ЗІХОДИТИ, джу, диш, недок., ЗІЙТИ, зійду, зійдеш,
> док.](http://sum.in.ua/s/skhodyty)
>
> **1.** Ідучи по рівному або ступаючи по сходинах, підніматися куди-небудь. **4.** Залишати яке-небудь місце, переходячи на інше; відхилятися від попереднього напрямку. ♦ Зійти з глузду — збожеволіти.

Як правильно потрібно сформувати питання, щоб не проштовхуватися.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дідусь, напевно, любитель жартів і анекдотів. Він дослівно повторив ситуацію з відомої жартівливої оповідки, де питання ставилися білявці. Але всепояснювальною відповіддю на питання "То що ж ви робите?" було "Вилізаю". Дідусь, напевно, саме його чекав, але ви позбавили його задоволення приголомшити почуттям гумору. Ваше питання було правильно поставленим. Пояснення є [тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/30/53399/25663.html):

> **ЗЛАЗИТИ , ВИЛАЗИТИ , ВСТАВАТИ , СХОДИТИ , ВИХОДИТИ**
>   **Сходити** – спускатися вниз (по
>   сходах, трапу); полишати своє місце, розташоване десь угорі; припиняти
>   рух, досягнувши кінцевої мети шляху; висаджуватися. Сходити з трибуни.
>   Сходити з корабля (з потяга). **Виходити** – рухатися зсередини транспорту
>   назовні. Виходити з вагона.  Коли йдеться про те, що пасажир залишає
>   під час зупинки трамвай, тролейбус, автобус, автомашину, слід вживати
>   дієслово виходити (“На якій зупинці ви виходите?”), *а не злазити,
>   вилазити, вставати, сходити*, як нерідко трапляється в усному мовленні.
>   Перші два слова в цьому випадку сприймаються як зниження стилю
>   (“Вилізла з трамвая на першій зупинці”. “Де ви злазите?”), решта – як
>   неточно вжиті: “На якій зупинці ви встаєте (сходите)?” Адже пасажир не
>   обов’язково сидить у трамваї – він може і стояти; сходити можна з
>   якогось підвищення, а види транспорту, про які мовиться, не
>   сприймаються як предмети, розташовані на певній висоті. Тому,
>   очевидно, немає підстав у цьому контексті вживати дієслово сходити.